# Default value reading vector of ints in logstash config

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, config, kibana

I have a vector of ints in a json field, I can access the elements and add a new field in the logstash config like this:

```
mutate{add_field  => { "MyField_0" => "%{[JsonField][0]}"}}
mutate{add_field  => { "MyField_1" => "%{[JsonField][1]}"}}
```

If my vector is [7, 9] the output is:

```
MyField_0 = 7
MyField_1 = 9
```

The problem is that the vector size is variable, sometimes the vector only has 1 element, and the output in kibana for the fields are:

```
MyField_0 = 7
MyField_1 = %{[JsonField][1]}
```

I want a default value to appear in the second value, like a 0, or a -1, can this be done? I'm new to ELK and have no knowledge of ruby :(.

Thank you for any indication,

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I got it to work with a translate filter similar to this:

```
filter{
  translate{
    field => "MyField_1" 
    destination => "NewField" 
    dictionary => ["%{[JsonField][1]}", "0"]
  }
}
```